# Afnetworking request get time out on iPhone 5 , iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ but works on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I have the following URL:

http://beta.bemembr.com/en/webservice/abc123/members/login/email/******/password/****

And this piece of code:

```
 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"en/webservice/%@/members/login/email/%@/password/%@",apiKey,login,pass];
    NSLog(@"PATH IS %@",path);
    [manager GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *json = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"JSON IS %@",json);
        int status = [[json valueForKey:@"status"] intValue];
        if(status == 200){
            compblock(YES);
        }else{
            compblock(NO);
        }
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
    {
         // Failure

         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
        compblock(NO);
    }];
```

This is working on an iPhone4 but fails on iPhone 5, iPhone6 and iPhone 6+

This is the error I got:

```
Failure: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x7f8951c5c7b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://beta.bemembr.com/en/webservice/abc123/members/login/email/*****/password/*****, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8951c82220 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://beta.bemembr.com/en/webservice/abc123/members/login/email/*****/password/*****}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks !

Comment: What iOS version is the iPhone 4 running, and what iOS version are your other devices running?  I've run into issues where iOS 8 is now more 'picky' about network requests than previous versions (see answers below for possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the username and password component of your URL, and try something like this instead.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://examplewebsite.com]];

[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking: [AFNetworking2.0] https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Add *UIKit+AFNetworking* and *AFNetworking* folder into your project.

and add this code in the file you want to use AFNetworking:

```
#import "AFnetworking.h"
#import "UIKit+AFNetworking.h"
```

And use this code:

```
-(void)login
{    
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:@"some_url" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }];
}
```

Since you are passing parameters within the URL String, set it to nil: `parameters:nil`